# How to trouble shoot the lag in the Django live server?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a small protein database. You can see the codes [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/228912/a-small-protein-database). Say a user searches for their proteins of interest from the database. They can add the sequences to the cart. Also, they can upload their custom data to the database using session. If the user clear the session their custom data will be removed. The purpose is to do additional analysis in the database (say pairwise alignments). The problem is when a user wants to clear session. After clearing the session still the html page shows the data. After ~60 seconds the session clears. I use anonymous sessions in the script.

The database works perfectly well locally. I couldn't figure out where the problem is. I tried both SQLite3 as well as PostgreSQL for the database. Still the problem persists.

```
"""
Django settings for database project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os, socket

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '*******************************************'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'database',
    'captcha',
    'crispy_forms',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'database.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join('templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'database.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)

on_production_server = True if socket.gethostname() == '*****' else False

DEBUG = True if not on_production_server else False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG
```

The following versions are used installed

```
attrs==19.1.0
biopython==1.73
captcha==0.3
certifi==2019.9.11
chardet==3.0.4
colorclass==2.2.0
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==2.1
django-crispy-forms==1.7.2
django-tables2==2.1.0
docopt==0.6.2
ete3==3.1.1
numpy==1.16.4
packaging==19.1
Pillow==6.1.0
pip-upgrader==1.4.15
psycopg2==2.7.6.1
psycopg2-binary==2.7.6.1
pyparsing==2.4.2
PyQt5==5.13.0
PyQt5-sip==4.19.18
pytz==2019.2
requests==2.22.0
six==1.12.0
sqlparse==0.3.0
terminaltables==3.1.0
urllib3==1.25.3
uWSGI==2.0.17.1
whitenoise==4.1.3
```

I use NGINX and uWSGI for deployment in the Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.6 (Maipo). The data in the database is very small (700 protein sequences). There are no system admins in our department. Hence I am looking for the answer online. I am new to web development framework (Django) as well as deploying. How to identify and troubleshoot the problem? Can you point me where the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with Django. It's with nginx configuration file. Added the below line

```
location / {    
         add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-store, no-cache,
         must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0'; expires off; }
```

Referred: https://ryanclouser.com/2015/07/16/nginx-Disable-Caching/